# How do I interpret dependency cycles in puppet?

Tags: puppet, apt

I have a puppet program that I'm trying to use stages in to better manage timing, but when I try that, nothing happens. I then tried to just use a dependency chain, but that throws back this error:

```
Error: Could not apply complete catalog: Found 1 dependency cycle:
(Anchor[apt::ppa::ppa:saltstack/salt] => Apt::Ppa[ppa:saltstack/salt] => class[Pp_package_manager] => Class[User_manager] => User_manager::User[coder] => User[coder] => File[/etc/default/perfectpitch] => Class[Pp_package_manager])
```

I'm trying to understand what this error is telling me, but the `=>` signs are confusing the heck out of me. I also tried to open up the .dot file using the `--graph` flag, but that just confuses me as well. I'd love a guiedhttps://gist.github.com/supereman16/1ff46d6fbb1c7ac9b709.

I'd love a guide on how to interpret these and possibly some help with where the problem actually is. Any help will be greatly appreciated in helping me understand this error, and the steps I should take to find the problem and fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this article about [relations and ordering](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_relationships.html) in puppet.

In summary. 
Puppet is a declarative language, where you describe a desired state of your system (not how to achieve it). So when it compiles manifests code to catalogue, it tries to establish order in which resources should be realized achieve desired state (it creates graph of dependencies).

E.g you cannot run mysql server unless you install mysql package.

Generally puppet properly solves relationships between resources. But sometimes it needs help. For each resource you can manually define relationship between other resources, using `before, require, notify, subscribe` metaparameters. Unfortunately, using these metaparameters you can easily create  a cycle of dependencies.

E.g

```
file { a: require => File['b'] }
file { b: require => File['c'] }
file { c: require => File['a'] }
```

Such declaration of resources will create a cycle of dependencies causing compilation error similar to what you have.

It the message you provide, `a => b` means do resource `a` before resource `b`. 
You got a cycle of dependencies: `...=> class[Pp_package_manager] => ... Class[Pp_package_manager]`. 
I'm guessing you have defined relationships `File[/etc/default/perfectpitch] => Class[Pp_package_manager]` and `class[Pp_package_manager] => Class[User_manager]` , which causes an error.

Comment: You were right. I just switched around pp_package_manager and user_manager and it worked... sort of. Now it just isn't running at all. See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254892/puppet-manifest-not-running